# Can i ask Manage external storage Permission for Password Saver Application?

Tags: android, android-studio, storage

I have a doubt that can I ask `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Permission for a Password Saver application to create a hidden backup\restore point for the users?
I searched here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files
but got only this and I am confused:

if your app includes a use case that's similar to the following examples, it's likely to be allowed to request the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission:

`File managers`
`Backup and restore apps`
`Anti-virus apps`
`Document management apps`
`On-device file search`
`Disk and file encryption`
`Device-to-device data migration`

Comment: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will only give access to storage locations all other apps can see too. What is it that you think it will solve?

Comment: i want to create a hidden folder and not a ASD

Comment: What is ASD? And what is a hidden folder? And where exactly do you wanna create that folder? Please read my comment again as all apps can see those folders.

Comment: you can use SharedPrefrences for saving passwords

Comment: Thanks, I got my solution. Sorry it's my mistake I didn't read your reply properly